# onResponse boolean instance variable is not being set?

Tags: java, android, json, boolean, response

I have an on click listener, and in that on click listener, I have an if, else statment, as follows

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postMethodRegister();
            System.out.println("mSuccess is set to " + mSuccess);
            if (mSuccess) {
                Intent login = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(login);
            }else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check your UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

I also have a boolean variable that is by default set to false, private boolean mSuccess; if the onResponse is executed I set it to true, else I set it to false and execute the appropriate response, but for some reason, the first attempt of a login it runs the onResponse, but when it gets to the onClick mSuccess is set to false what is up with that? mSuccess is a instance variable.

```
 public void postMethodRegister() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("On Response was thrown in Login"+response);
            mSuccess=true;
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error was thrown in Login" + error.getMessage()+"and the response code is ");
            mSuccess=false;

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postMethodRegister()` method makes an asynchronous request.

So , when you click your button `onClick()` gets invoked which in turn invokes `postMethodRegister()` . 
Then `postMethodRegister()` makes an asynchronous network request which means your network request will run in another thread and then your control will move immediately to the next line after `postMethodRegister()` which is  `System.out.println("mSuccess is set to " + mSuccess);`. Now at this point since you haven't got response from `onResponse()` so  `mSuccess` will be unchanged (and will be false).

Comment: I see that makes alot of  sense! Any quick solutions that you propose to this problem?

Comment: You can write if block code in onResponse() and else block code in onErrorResponse() after removing both blocks from onClick().